# Is there a way to stop this from happening to buttons with images in them?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style

So every time i add images to a button this effect happens, usually when brushing over the button.

i assume it has something to do with the default button mouse over effect but so far i've had no luck with changing the default style and this effect keeps happening. is this just wpf being wpf or something that shouldn't usually happen.

Button before mousing over/ brushing over:

[image: button before mousing over/ brushing over]

Wrongly displayed button:

[image: erroneous button]

```
<Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="savebutton" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="savebutton_Click">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="Images/folder.png" Width="40" Height="40" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: That XAML looks ok. Is there anything else, e.g. a Button Style?

Comment: @Clemens no button style for this one, it's just using the default style with an image as content. the same effect happens on buttons with just text in them when i mouse over them although way less frequent than with images. if i disabled the button being clickable this doesnt happen but then i lose the purpose xd.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't sound plausible. With only the XAML you are showing here, nobody will actually be able to help.

Comment: I downloaded your image and put it on a button in a test project. Moving the mouse over the button does not do what you show. Try putting it a new project yourself to see if the same problem occurs. If it works fine in your new project, then something *else* in the current project is causing this.